# Deleted Drive Map via GPO Still Showing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, mappeddrive

I have a mapped gpo drives configured on my Windows Server 2012r2 and it works great when mapping a drive. The issue is when I delete a drive b/c it is no longer needed, it still reappears even after gpupdate /force command is run on both the DC and the end user's machine. After a reboot of the end user's machine, it still reappears. When I run net use command, it still shows that the drive is mapped but I have no access to it.

What am I doing wrong? Why does this drive not want to go away after gpupdate /force and even after a reboot?

Comment: I'm assuming you're deleting it with GPP in the same GPO?

Comment: Yes that is correct. When I go into the GPP, I open up the specific mapped drive, change the action from Replace to Delete and apply the changes. I then do a gpupdate /force, restart my workstation and the drive is still there, I just don't have access to it.

Comment: Does the delete operation shows correct in the gpresult output? There might be a sync issue between your DC's

Comment: I'm not showing anything in the gpresult output that says anything about the delete operation.

Comment: When I ran the command gpresult /user username /h c:\gpo.html /f, I did see where "changes were detected" for the Drive Maps but no change on my pc.

Comment: Nevermind, I suppose deleting the drive actually worked. It took some time but it worked. I get impatient, especially with GPOs.